# Does anyone know what the name of the tech that displays graphics in a terminal window on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, terminal

What i mean by that question is, like when installing nvidia drivers manually. you will either leave the CLI to display some graphics to install the driver or the graphics part just goes full screen or something.

this is an image of install a xmbc os.

[image]

Just want to be able to pop up a graphical screen from and within the terminal similar to the picture. its looks like graphics has some pixel control to is. it doesnt look like highlighted text.

Plus is there is something that can interface with a touch screen for the touch clicking.

probably going to be doing this all through ssh or straight off the device!

The language that i know most is C++.

Answer (score 1):

These are ncurses: http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html

You can do all kinds of fancy console stuff with this library.

If you need a simpler (and somewhat more limited way) to build such GUIs, you can use a dialog utility, directly from a shell script: http://invisible-island.net/dialog/ (it uses ncurses internally).

Both ncurses and dialog are typically available out of the box on most distros.

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot looks like it was made with [Newt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_%28programming_library%29).  It's actually using text mode, so it's not really graphics.  It's using the text-mode screen as a "character-cell" display, where the software can change the character and colors at any location on the screen at any time, rather than as a "teletype" (tty), which can only print new lines at the bottom and scroll upward.

There's a lower-level library called [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), which provides basic character-cell display functionality.  You can use that to build a completely custom text-mode UI, or use a UI library such as [Dialog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_%28software%29) which builds on top of it.

I don't know if Newt supports mouse input — from a quick look at the docs, it doesn't appear to — but ncurses and Dialog do, so if your touchscreen system can translate touch input into virtual mouse events, you should be able to handle those from an ncurses-based UI.